# How to run the packager for the React Native official examples on Windows?

Tags: android, windows, reactjs, react-native

Following thiss guide https://github.com/facebook/react-native#examples
after cloning the official repo and running successfully

> gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug

the next step in the guide is

> Start the packager in a separate shell (make sure you ran npm install):
>   ./packager/packager.sh

Unfortunately i cannot run shell scripts on windows, yet. What can I do?

---

after trying the suggestion by @whitep4nther, running `node "./local-cli/cli.js" start` gives me the following error

```
Looking for JS files in
   D:\dev\sources\react-native

 ERROR  FileWatcher is not a function
TypeError: FileWatcher is not a function
    at new Server (index.js:189:9)
    at Object.createServer (D:\dev\sources\react-native\packager\react-packager\index.js:107:10)
    at getPackagerServer (runServer.js:74:24)
    at runServer (runServer.js:29:26)
    at startServer (server.js:148:3)
    at _server (server.js:144:3)
    at server.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (D:\dev\sources\react-native\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (D:\dev\sources\react-native\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (D:\dev\sources\react-native\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:66:3)
```

running node 5.10.0 npm 3.8.3 Windows 10 x64
any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you will only be able to develop Android apps.

You can follow [this page](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html#content) fully to get started - there is each time a step for Windows environments.

---

After running npm install in `react-native/`, run

`node "./local-cli/cli.js" start`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to run an Android official example app on windows, the problem is that i don't know how to start the packager.    
`react-native start` works of on a project created with `init`, but not on the official example app. I'm missing something.

Comment: I edited my post, the command is simply what you can find in the shell script : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/packager.sh

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, but i still get an error as described above and I can't figure it out if it's a problem with FileWatcher ar it's my configuration
(running node 5.10.0, npm 3.8.3)

Comment: @raduf Did you run `npm install` in the `react-native/` folder ?

Comment: yes i did, I  have tried deleting the folder and re-running npm install, i have checked that the node-haste module contain FileWatcher. I'm out of things to try at the moment

Comment: Well, I don't have a windows environment right now. I will be trying the whole process tomorrow on my own laptop and see if I can get the example working right

Comment: I did a fresh git checkout, ran the commands and everything went smoothly. Thanks again